# Winforms Numeric updown control, how to set a specific set of values

Tags: winforms

I see that I can set Minimum, Maximum, Increment properties for this control.

Is it possible to set the control **to the specified set?** for example:

2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 36, 48, 72

Comment: You mean like a ComboBox?  Use a ComboBox.

Comment: ...or if dead set against a ComboBox, you can try a DomainUpDown control, too.

Comment: Not having a lot of experience with the Winforms, I guess, I will try one of your suggestions.  Thanks you.